# How "Follow" button works in Graph DB

Tags: graph-databases, titan

I am using Titan Graph DB. I want to implement "follow" button in my page i.e I a page update something, it should be know to all follower. I dont know how does this follow mechanism work.

In social networking when we **follow** something we keep getting all updates from that page. How does it work? What is the idea behind implementing this in Graph DB.

Suppose I am following a page **XYZ** and there happend one update on XYZ. then how does it sends its update info to all followers.

- Is it something that it will store update info for all individual
  user in graph DB
- OR Is it like when a user login it will check all page that it follow
  for any new update?
- OR something else

Comment: Simplest implementation: add a link between the person and the followed thing. When a new update arrives, just trigger a lookup on the DB and all the out vertices (people following it) returning should be updated.

Comment: are you saying that new update should be saved for each and every individual who is following? When a user login how should he get new updates from following page?

Answer (score 1):

The process to trigger the notification has nothing todo with the underlying database you use. This is part of your business logic, how you design your application and how you notify all the listeners about the change.

A graph database will give you the opportunity to store the information about your users and theire tweets, or your sites and the follower in a more natural and semantic way.

In a graph database, you can store your Persons, e.g. `John` and `Doe` as `Vertices` and a relation or edge between them, labeled with `follows`. In your SQL database, you would store them in a separate table plus a table for your joins to store all the followers.

If you now have a new tweet, you have to join your tables in your SQL table to find all followers to notify. In a graph database, you just have to check the incoming edges on the person who wrote the tweet. Also, in the graph database, you could store the tweet as well, where an extra edge from the person who wrote it goes to the tweet, to have all the necessary informations for your notification at one place, instead of lots of lookups in SQL tables.